# How to convert Hexadecimal to ASCII values in java?

Tags: java

Thanks for your answer... I have 31 32 2E 30 31 33 6byte hexadecimal number. I want to convert 31 32 2E 30 31 33 this 6 byte hexadecimal number into 12.013 ASCII number in java.

Comment: Why do you think that these numbers are equal? For the first look your first (hex) number is much much bigger then the second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
byte[] bytes = {0x31, 0x32, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x31, 0x33};
String result = new String(bytes, "ASCII");
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant method but try this:

```
char[6] string = new char[6];
string[0] = 0x31;
string[1] = 0x32;
string[2] = 0x2E;
string[3] = 0x30;
string[4] = 0x31;
string[5] = 0x33;

String s = new String(string);

int result = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is an array of strings representing the digits in hex, you can do the following:

```
public static String convert(String[] hexDigits){
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hexDigits.length];

    for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
        bytes[i] = Integer.decode("0x"+hexDigits[i]).byteValue();

    String result;
    try {
        result = new String(bytes, "ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that the code assumes that the digits are given as valid ASCII values, with no radix specifier.